# Inject properties name into class anotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Is it possible to inject property name into the procedureName? 
im using spring boot.
Try to use the next the next construction:

```
procedureName = "${procedure}"  but it doesnt work
```

Also to write the special  PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer i think it not  a good idea .

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({

        @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "test",
                procedureName = "${procedure}",
                parameters = {

                })

})

public class R
```

try to get property from properties-test.yml

Answer (score 0):

Spring properties used to inject values in bean properties like below,

```
public class ClassWithInjectedProperty {

@Value("${props.foo}")
private String foo;
}
```

you case is not valid for value injection.

Comment: procedureName = "${props.procedure}" also doesnt work

Comment: but you put the example how to inject into field and i ask how to inject under class in simple way